# Trying to extract matches from a string matching an expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have spent two days on this and I can't figure it out. Sorry to sound specific. I am trying to match phone numbers in a string and store them in an array. For example:

```
// An example string
let string = "30000 loaves of bread were purchased by +1777654352"

// I got this from https://ihateregex.io/expr/phone/ and it works for my purpose
const regex = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/gmi

// I expect found to have [+1777654352]
const found = string.match(regex);
```

Instead, I keep getting `null` in my `found` array. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I hope someone out there can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex has ^ on the beginning and $ in the end so I'm pretty sure it matches only on phone numbers that are separated by line breaks, or that are alone in their String.

This regex should work for your needs:

```
let string = "30000 loaves of bread were purchased by +1777654352"

const regex = /[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}/gmi;

const found = string.match(regex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me!
I was using the regular expression poorly. Using the `^` and `$` flags were causing the issue. They signify the start and end of the string and hopefully someone can explain why it behaves that way. Removing those made `string.match(regex)` work as expected.